# Select from several partitions at once

Tags: sql, oracle, database-partitioning

Excuse me for my english. 
I have 2 tables, both partitioned by date interval, but on different fields.
There is a big amount of records in both tables(~100kk in each partition).
First table keep it's 3 last(by date) partitions in fast discks tablespace, others partitions is in slow discks tablespace.
Also I have some system, which processing data. It execute processes in parallel, each one get data from first table by select statement and put processed data into second table. 
So I need select data from first table only from "fast"(!) partitions to put it in second table.
But second table partitioned on other(date too) field. And when processes executing in parallel I get deadlocks when different processes trying to put data into the same partition in 2nd table.

Good solution is for each process take data from only "fast" partitions(but all of them in one time) only data for one partition in 2nd table. In this case each process will push data in one partition. But I don't have any idea how to do it.

If I make

```
select t.field1, t.field2 from (select * from FIRST_TABLE partition("P1") union all
select * from FIRST_TABLE partition("P2") union all
select * from FIRST_TABLE partition("P3")) t
where t.field3='someVal' --Indexed field in FIRST_TABLE
```

will OracleDB use local indexes on partitions in FIRST_TABLE to resolve where-clause? How will this way affect the performance?

Any ideas to solve my problem?

PS It's a lot of questions about how to select data from several partitions in one select-statement, but I didn't found answer usefull for my situation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does one do a SQL select over multiple partitions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4268139/how-does-one-do-a-sql-select-over-multiple-partitions)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You almost never want to use the `PARTITION` clause when querying a partitioned table.  You almost always want to specify a predicate that allows Oracle to do partition pruning on its own.

```
SELECT t.column1, t.column2
  FROM first_table t
 WHERE t.partitioned_date_column >= <<date that delimits fast partitions>>
   AND t.column3 = 'someVal'
```

When you specify a predicate on the date column that the table is partitioned on, Oracle can automatically determine which partition(s) need to be accessed.

Comment: What if I will need to move one of older partition into fast tablespace and  reprocess data(sorry, I didn't wrote about this restriction in question)? This way doesn't allow to define separated partition? not laying one after another.

Comment: @Andrey - I'm not sure how that changes anything.  You would still want to specify a predicate on `partitioned_date_column` that specifies which partitions need to be read from.  If you are saying that the date ranges are potentially non-contiguous, you may need a couple of predicates that are `OR`'d together rather than a `>=` or you may need an `IN` list.

Comment: If I write

    `AND( g.create_date  >= to_date('2013-09-01','yyyy-mm-dd')
    OR g.create_date  >= to_date('2013-06-01','yyyy-mm-dd') )`

it take all partitions after 2013-06-01(because it relate to condition), isn't it?

Comment: @Andrey - Well, yes, if you code it that way.  If you want everything since 9/1 and everything from 6/1 to 6/30, for example, you'd want the `OR` condition to be a `BETWEEN` or a `>= date '2013-06-01' and <= date '2013-06-30'`.  Your condition would need to match whatever set of date values you want to process.

Comment: Is this caused by the optimizer, how to get data from table - from exect partitions or full scan whole table to check the condition? How can I check that in case of `and( g.create_date  between to_date('2013-09-01','yyyy-mm-dd') and add_months(to_date('2013-09-01','yyyy-mm-dd'),1)
or g.create_date  between to_date('2013-06-01','yyyy-mm-dd') and add_months(to_date('2013-06-01','yyyy-mm-dd'),1) )` condition, DB using only partitions I specified? It is unacceptable to using somehow of slow disks(performance is critical).
Sory for my meticulousness, I just want to be shure=)

Comment: @Andrey - The query plan will show that partition elimination is taking place.  You'll see a `PSTART` and `PSTOP` of `KEY` and the predicate will show the predicate.

Comment: For query
`SELECT   *
  FROM   FIRST_TABLE  g,
         SOME_OTHER_TABLE s
 WHERE  flag_entry = 'Y'
         and  g.COLUMN1 = s.COLUMN1
         and  g.COLUMN2 = s.COLUMN2
         and g.COLUMN3  between to_date('2013-07-01','yyyy-mm-dd') and add_months(to_date('2013-07-01','yyyy-mm-dd'),1) --SECOND_TABLE (OUT) partitioned by same value
and( g.create_date  between to_date('2013-09-01','yyyy-mm-dd') and add_months(to_date('2013-09-01','yyyy-mm-dd'),1)
or g.create_date  between to_date('2013-06-01','yyyy-mm-dd') and add_months(to_date('2013-06-01','yyyy-mm-dd'),1) )`

Comment: I see plan like this(in PL/SQLDeveloper), :
It did not fit in the previous post, here is only part about FIRST_TABLE.
`PX RECEIVE
--PX SEND HASH SYS :TQ10001
----PX BLOCK ITERATOR
------TABLE ACCESS FULL SCH FIRST_TABLE`
Here is no `PSTART` or `PSTOP` in it.
Is it possible to make new lines in post? Can not find how.

Comment: @Andrey - You can certainly edit your post.  I'd use `dbms_xplan` to generate your query plan rather than relying on any GUI.  Most GUIs do not display all the columns that are available.

Comment: @Justin Cave - Thank You, You realy help me)

Comment: @JustinCave Would you please explain "You almost never want to use the PARTITION clause when querying a partitioned table."? For example I like to launch 1 thread against each partition for batched jobs, and will often use the PARTITION clause for queries. Is this no good?

Answer (score 0):

you can get deadlock if you are trying to execute three queries in parallel on your own, for example running at the same time:

```
insert into t2 select from t1 partition ("P1");
```

and then in another shell/window/job:

```
insert into t2 select from t1 partition ("P2")
```

If you query

```
select *
from t1
where date_column_used_for_partition >= 3_dates_ago
```

Oracle will select only the three partitions that you need and you won't need to use `UNION`.

In this way you can put your `INSERT INTO... SELECT` statement in a single query and you don't need to worry about deadlock, the Oracle engine will know in which partition of the second table it has to insert the data and he will manage the inserts for you.