# Counting rows in multiple partitions using Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, partition

For a partitioned table I can count the rows in a partition quickly with a query like this:

```
select count(*)
from db.table Partition (P)
where column value is Null
```

Is there a way to do this for multiple partitions?

My desired result is the following-

```
Partition name         Count of Null Rows
P1                         20000
P2                         12000
P3                          30000
```

Answer (score 2):

It won't be as efficient as using `FROM TABLE PARTITION (p)`, but you could do this:

```
select o.object_name, o.subobject_name partition, count(*) 
from sh.sales s 
inner join all_objects o on o.object_id = dbms_rowid.rowid_object(s.rowid)
where o.subobject_name in ('SALES_Q1_2000','SALES_Q2_2000')
-- for performance, you can add conditions to restrict to the partitions of interest, if you know them
-- e.g., and s.sale_date between to_date('01-JAN-2000','DD-MON-YYYY') and to_date('30-JUN-2000','DD-MON-YYYY')
group by o.object_name, o.subobject_name;
```

Basically, it uses the `rowid` to determine the partition for each row and counts them.

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered before. If your table is not partitioned on date, simply change the predicate and allow Oracle to do the work for you. Many thanks to Mr. Cave :)

[Select from several partitions at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19523061/select-from-several-partitions-at-once)

> You almost never want to use the PARTITION clause when querying a
>   partitioned table. You almost always want to specify a predicate that
>   allows Oracle to do partition pruning on its own.
>
> > SELECT t.column1, t.column2
> >        FROM first_table t
> >     WHERE t.partitioned_date_column >= <> AND t.column3 = 'someVal'
>
> When you specify a predicate on the date
>   column that the table is partitioned on, Oracle can automatically
>   determine which partition(s) need to be accessed.

Comment: The OP wants the result set to show a breakdown of rows by partition.  Can you please clarify how you accomplish that with your approach?

Comment: There is already a better answer posted, but by using count(*) in the select statement, OP could get the number of rows in each partition by manipulating the where clause to match the same condition(s) that have been used for table partitioning

Comment: My partition is based on a company id. Which is a ranged partition is that something that would work?

Comment: Hi Jae, yep! You could do a where clause that looks something like where company id between 0 and x, etc.

Answer (score 0):

After gathering statistics (with the default, auto-sample size), the numbers can be retrieved almost instantly with this query:

```
select partition_name, num_nulls
from all_part_col_statistics
where owner = user
    and table_name = 'TABLE_NAME'
    and column_name = 'COLUMN_NAME'
order by partition_name;
```

Comment: Those numbers will still be estimates

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name For 11g+, the numbers will be accurate unless you explicitly change the sample size.  By default, Oracle reads the whole table and will be 100% accurate for the number of rows and the number of nulls.